# Stripe metadata not shown on dashboard

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

i'm implementing stripe susbscription service in laravel using laravel cashier, on the strip dashboard under the metadata tag there is no metadata despite i am sending it as i can see the metadata under the "Event Data" json response.

My Code

```
$metadata= [
                'customer_email'=>Auth::user()->email,
                'pet_name'=>$pet->name,
                'pet_id'=>$pet->id,
                'plan_type'=>$plan_type,
                'order_id'=>Order::latest()->first()==null?1:Order::latest()->first()->id+1,
            ];

            $payment_success=Auth::user()->newSubscription($plan_type,$plan_stripe_id)
                                         ->withMetadata($metadata)
                                         ->create($request->paymentMethod,
                                             ['email' => Auth::user()->email,]
                                         );
```

I also tried changing

```
 ->withMetadata($metadata)
```

with

```
->withMetadata(['metadata'=>'this is a test'])
```

but it has the same results
I want the metadata because i am configuring a webhook and in that webhook i am not getting the metadta without that i cannot query my database.

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please write into Support and share with them the Subscription ID so they can look into this?  https://support.stripe.com/contact/email